# Short story featuring a detective and his alien sidekick

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story featuring a bumbling human private investigator and his hyper-competent space-alien sidekick.  In the story, it's noted that where most intelligent species have evolved from predators, the sidekick's species evolved from scavengers.  This comes up when the sidekick refers to a dead body as a "corpus delectable", and then needs to clarify that this wasn't established by tasting.

Google searches are hitting a dead end, because there's a non-science-fiction murder mystery that uses that phrase as the title.

This would have been published in a science-fiction magazine, probably *Analog*, in the 1980s or 1990s.

Comment: there was a tv series, with Mandy Patimkin playing an alien detective. it could have been alien nation or a spin off.

Comment: This would be an excellent idea to spin off the MIB universe.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is probably "[Garbage In, Garbage Out](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43646)" (1995) by Grey Rollins, published as far as ISFDb knows, only in *Analog*, December 1995 (vol 115, issue 14).

> "Dead body?  What do you mean, dead body?"
>
> "One from which life has departed, you idiot!  A stiff! A carcass!  **A corpus delectable!**"
>
> Martin's face twisted in horror.  "**Corpus *delectable?***  You didn't!  You wouldn't dare!"
>
> "Martin," I said.
>
> "I mean, it's bad enough—"
>
> "Martin!"
>
> "And if the relatives heard you talking about **how their dearly beloved had *tasted*—**"
>
> *"Martin!"*

Victor, the alien, has "six-inch legs" and a very long, prehensile tongue:

> Desperate to get his attention, I unfurled two or three feet of my tongue, reached through the open window and slapped him across the face several times in quick succession

And he is a scavenger, as you recall:

> Like the corpse, I am an extraterrestrial, albeit of a different species.  The climate of my home world is two or three notches above what humans call tropical.  **My species evolved as scavengers on the forest floor**, eating the remains of both plant and animal matter even as it decayed.

Answer (score 21):

You're thinking of Grey Rollin's "Martin and Victor" [stories](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?26140) published in Analog from 1990 to 2004 - in particular the December 1995 story "Garbage In, Garbage Out"

This [review](https://tangentonline.com/print-monthly/analog/analog-june-2004/) of one of them has this description of  the series

> "On the Tip of My Tongue" by Grey Rollins is part of a series
> featuring about Martin Crofts, private detective, and his partner
> Victor. Victor is an alien of unknown origin, as well as the brains of
> the team, and the story is told from his point of view. With the rent
> already overdue, Martin and Victor are glad to have a client at last,
> one Deems Warden of Liquitrans Incorporated, who suspects his partner,
> Evan Bartles, of stealing sensitive material from him.

This excerpt of ["Garbage In, Garbage Out"](https://books.google.com/books?id=97gnAQAAIAAJ&q=%22corpus%20delectable%22%20analog&dq=%22corpus%20delectable%22%20analog&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE15Oa7qz9AhXPFlkFHZyhB8gQ6AF6BAgJEAI) includes the phrase "Corpus delectable."