# Detective story with an alien that looked like celery

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, detective

This is a short story from an anthology published before 2000.

It was told from the point of view of an alien who was a friend or side-kick to a human detective. The alien walked and talked but looked like a large celery plant. Humans had nicknamed its race "Celeries", and at one point a bowl of chopped celery was sent as a threat. Celeries could occasionally pick up human thoughts, when the human was under stress.

The plot involved a young human woman who the detective found attractive. During conversation with another human, the Celery received a mental image of that character in an intimate position with the same woman, showing he knew her and was linked to the plot.

The Celery's body stored its waste in a pod that would burst open violently if it was not relieved regularly. This happened during the story, leading the detective to comment that the dung had hit the fan.

Comment: Related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272461/short-story-featuring-a-detective-and-his-alien-sidekick ?

Comment: Possibly "Celery, stalks and all" by  Isaac Asimov. Not posting it as an answer as I can't find any links to it that even suggests this book exists but it featured an alien protagonist who is a member of the 'celery' species and worked as a sidekick to a human detective. The Celery's body produced explosive waste that it kept in a pod that had to be emptied.

Comment: @Hukk2010 That definitely sounds like it, thanks.

Comment: @JonCuster I can't rule it out but I don't remember the Celeries having long tongues or being carrion-eaters, so I don't think so.

Comment: @Hukk2010 No such story exists by any author.  You got that from a chatbot, right?