# 70's or 80's sci fi novel about a human who runs afoul of a sentient celery plant whose wife or ex-wife is a panda

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a book I read as a kid where the main character was a human (who are rare out in space) and he runs afoul of a merchant on a ship or space station who is a sentient celery plant whose wife or ex-wife is a panda. So the kid ends up working for the celery and then going on some expedition with him where cryosleep is involved and then they come back with either a lot of money or secrets or technology and I think they help fight off an attack on their space station or mega ship or whatever it is.

Comment: If you find it elsewhere, please let us know - https://www.reddit.com/r/printSF/comments/16yulmt/looking_for_an_older_book/

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, when were you 'a kid'? What was the name of the space station? Was this set near Earth or around another planet? What was the kid's name? Does he grow up over the course of the story or is this a vignette? Who's attacking them? How do they defeat the attack?

Comment: Can we for the love of all that is holy write descriptive question titles? Think: would this prompt be enough for Google? If not, rewrite it.

Comment: Is it any relation to [Detective story with an alien that looked like celery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272477/detective-story-with-an-alien-that-looked-like-celery)? It doesn't look obviously related but you wouldn't have thought alien celeries were that common.

Comment: Ah, but we fell into that fallacy on the "Welsh space-pirates" question @JohnRennie

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez True :-)